# Download not working in iframe inside ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, iframe, ionic4

i'm beginner in Ionic

the download function in my website doesn't work (it doesn't show anything) if the web is run in an iframe embedded in IONIC 4, like this:

```
<ion-content fullscreen>
<iframe src="http://www.myweb.com" scrolling="yes" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

but if the web is run on a browser such as opera, chrome, mozilla, and others, the download function works fine.

How to solve this problem, thanks...

Comment: because your application dont have file permissions. and you can't download file from ionic iframe.

Comment: where should i add file permission ? thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using  in you app, try using inAppBrowser:

installation:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser
ionic cap sync
```

then in ts file:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
openPage(){
let browser = this.iab.create('http://www.myweb.com', '_blank'
      , {
        
        lefttoright: 'yes',
        hideurlbar: 'no',
        fullscreen: 'yes',
        hardwareback: 'yes',
        toolbarcolor: '#145a7b',
        zoom: 'no',
        useWideViewPort: 'no',
        hidenavigationbuttons: 'no',
        footer: 'yes',
        message: "Hello",
        toolbar : 'yes',
        location: 'yes'
      }
    );
}
```

In html:

```
<ion-button (click)="openPage()">Open Page</ion-button>
```

Comment: when i'm write code above in ts file, my page html cannot showing, when i'm write constructor like this:

constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {}

Comment: @JaySlavara I did not understand what issue you are facing, however i will reiterate on this. You have defined constructor correctly. The difference between iframe and inAppBrowser is that iframe embeds you page in the app. It might give you cross origin error. However in inappbrowser your page opens widely and in fullscreen mode. As ionic  uses native browser's instance. Similarly inappbrowser is another instance of browser that opens you web page. You can find enough examples.